# How to get directive element width in my case

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get element width within a directive.

I have something like

html

```
 <my-dir  title=“toy.title” ng-if=“toy.name”></my-dir>
```

directive

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module(‘myApp’)
        .directive(‘myDir’, myDir);

    function myDir() {
        var directive = {
            template: '<div class=“myClass”>Test here</div>',
            restrict: 'E',
            controller: testCtrl
        };

        return directive;
    }

    function testCtrl($element) {
        console.log($element[0].clientWidth()) -> output 0
    }
})();
```

I need to get the element width to build my feature but it outputs 0 when it has string `‘Test here’`  in the element. It should be greater  than 0. I am not sure what went wrong, can someone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you add your controller class? If it doesn't, you should add a controller class to this structure

Comment: You sure `clientWidth` is a method of HTML DOM nodes?  I've always accessed it as a property.  Maybe it works as a function call too?  I mean `$element[0].clientWidth` VS `$element[0].clientWidth()`

Answer (score 0):

**Consider:**

This is a bit of a tricky problem as there is no guarantee that the DOM has rendered at the time the controller initializes.

Furthermore, what if the user resizes the window and the element changes size?  Give consideration to what you're using the element's dimensions for and if the possibility of it changing size matters for your use case.

**Solutions:**

I've used a few different approaches, and I wouldn't consider any of them to be perfect.  But they do work and different ones are more suitable for different use cases.

Probably quickest + dirtiest approach: use a `$timeout` or `$interval` that checks the width after or at certain time delays.

Another way is to run a `$watch` on a function that returns the element's width.

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
    return $element[0].clientWidth;
}, function(width){
    console.log('width of: ', width);
});
```

**A Practical Example:**

The most common use case in my app is something like this:

1. directive initializes + makes async request to load content
2. content request resolves, set data into `$scope` variable and `$emit('contentLoaded')`
3. a `bounds-watcher` directive is listening for `$scope.$on('contentLoaded', checkBounds);`
4. `function checkBounds(){ ... }` starts an `$interval` to poll the element's dimensions

**Window Resize?**

If you're dealing with a responsive layout, you will probably want to handle your dimension logic when the window is resized as well as when the directive first loads.  It's worth it to give consideration to that when you set up your dimension handler functions.